# SSIS - Import from CSV to Staging Table

Tags: sql-server, csv, ssis, staging

I am new to SSIS, I want to import some data from CSV and put it in the staging table. Can anyone help me and send a step by step procedure. I have spent a whole day on it and couldn't understand the concept of staging table. Your help will be appreciated. If anyone can explain Staging tables with example, it will be good.

Comment: Can you post code of what you've tried? Where are you having difficulties? We're not a doing work for you service

Answer (score 0):

Staging table is nothing but a "table". But it is not your final or target table where you want your data to reside in the end. Stage tables are table which may contain the data temporarily before you move them into your target table.

For example, you have a source table/file (let's say SRC) from where you want to move data into target table (lets's say TGT) periodically. But you don't want to load the data that is already there in TGT again. In this case you use a staging table (STG).

For each time you want to load data, first you clear STG and load all the data from SRC to STG. Then you can compare between STG and TGT to move over only the new records.

Hope this helps.